# Nested scrollview with table view in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a scroll (Scroll view 1) view which contains profile View and Custom Segmented Control which replaces the content in the nested scroll view (Scroll view 2). On segmented control tab change I added the table view inside nested scroll view (Scroll view 2). I am not able to scroll to the whole view. How can I achieve this?

[image: Nested Scroll View]

[image: Segmented View]

Comment: you want your internal scroll scrolling independent? or scrolling all together?

Comment: I want to scroll all together.... @reinier

Answer (score 8, accepted):

one simple solution is to calculate your nested scroll's content height and give it a fixed height constraint so it wont be able to scroll by itself anymore
but a little more complicated solution is [HERE](https://sexyswift.wordpress.com/2016/08/25/swift-parallax-scrolling-with-header-sticking-at-top-nested-uiscrollview/)

I hope it helps